# Automate create text files from Excel

Tags: excel, text-files, vba

Any way to create separate text files which contain different ID. I want the text files to be named with content of "Starting_Year.

For example:

```
Starting_Year    Code        ID
------------------------------------
1982            ALLRIN     400200583
1983            ALLRIN     000083522
1983            ALLRIN     400200583
```

this will be created two text files, which named "1982", "1983". And "1982" file contains "400200583", also "1983" file contains "000083522" and "400200583".

Comment: Perfectly possible. What have you tried? You can filter your dataset and export to a file and record it as a macro to see what VBA code is generated as a start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the Scripting.FileSystemObject for this.

Basically, create a  FileSystemObject object and create file which returns a Text Stream. Then using the TextStream object, you can write your data...

The function to use is:

```
Public Function CreateTextFile(FileName As String, Optional Overwrite As Boolean = True, Optional Unicode As Boolean = False) As Scripting.TextStream
End Function
```

You supply a name and call it something like:

```
Dim oTs as Scripting.TextStream
set oTs = CreateTextFile(......)
oTs.Write(....)
```

Hope that helps.